# Run do_shortcode on php template using JS function

Tags: php, javascript, templates

I want to run a shortcode using the `[jobs]` on my PHP template. I'm using the WP Job Manager plugin. A sample code:

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $company_name = esc_attr(urldecode(get_query_var(apply_filters('wp_job_manager_companies_company_slug', 'company'))));
?>
    <a href="#" onclick="test(); return false;"> test </a>
    <span id="php_code"> </span>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function test(){
       phpTest = "<?php echo "json_encode(do_shortcode(\'\[jobs post_status='publish' keywords='" .$company_name. "'\]'));"; ?>";
       document.getElementById("php_code").innerHTML = phpTest;
    }
    </script>
```

This outputs the actual text, but I want to actually run the `do_shortcode()` function of WordPress so that it outputs whatever the `[jobs]` shortcode does. Using `<?php echo do_shortcode(params); ?>` on the template actually works. I'm creating a custom function using radio buttons.

Reference for code I found at the internet: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/312161/php-innerhtml-and-blank-spaces

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search led me to this: You can't run PHP with javascript. JavaScript is a client side technology (runs in the users browser) and PHP is a server side technology (run on the server). If you want to do this you have to make an ajax request to a PHP script and have that return the results you are looking for.